# android server message is not displaying on chat screen

Tags: android, xmpp

I am making an chatting application (using the asmack library).

It is working properly from client side; when client or user 1 sends a message to the server, the server receives message.

But when the server responds to that client, the value is showing only in logcat and not on the chat screen.

here is image

[image]

The message is received by the server.

[image: The message is received by the server]

When the server replies to the client the client doesn't get any output.
[image: An image of logcat]

but it is not displaying on client screen.

Here is my code

servicexmpp.java

```
PacketFilter filter;       

commanInstance.connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        chat = (Message) packet;
        System.out.println("<--- msg " + chat.getBody());
        String name = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(chat.getFrom());
        commanInstance.setProperJID(name);
        final String fromName=removeAtTheRateFromString(name);
        boolean listExistOrNot;
        listExistOrNot=commanInstance.listExistOrNot(fromName);
        imageName= "patientchat";
        jid=fromName;
        messagePacketID=chat.getPacketID();
    }
}, filter);
```

adapter.java

```
 public class MyListAdapterTwoLine extends BaseAdapter {
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private List<ItemTwoLine> mListe;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
String checkNameOfView;

SharedPreferences myPrefs; 
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
XMPPObjectPass commanInstance;//chatScreen
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public MyListAdapterTwoLine(Context context, List<ItemTwoLine> mListe,String nameOfView) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mListe = mListe;
    this.context=context;
    this.checkNameOfView=nameOfView;
    myPrefs = this.context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", this.context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    commanInstance=(XMPPObjectPass)context.getApplicationContext();
}//public MyListAdapterTwoLine(Context context, List<ItemTwoLine> mListe,String nameOfView) {
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListe.size();
}//public int getCount() 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mListe.get(position);
}//public Object getItem(int position)  
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}//public long getItemId(int position) { 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView doctorStatus;
}//static class ViewHolder { 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Drawable getRegistredImage() {

    return context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.register);
}//public Drawable getGreenImage()
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public Drawable getRestrictedImage() {

    return context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.restrict);
}//public Drawable getRedImage() 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

    ImageView doctorStatus,myImage1;
    TextView nameOfChatter, Msg,TimeDate;
    ImageView deliver;
    if(checkNameOfView.equals("GroupChatTalkScreen"))
    {

        //          if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("Me"))
        //          {
        //              convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftchat,null);
        //
        //              doctorStatus= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        //              doctorStatus.setImageDrawable(mListe.get(position).getImage());
        //              myImage1= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage1);
        //
        //
        //              nameOfChatter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfChatter);
        //              if(mListe.get(position).getTexte1().contains("#:#"))
        //              {
        //                  String nameAndText[]=mListe.get(position).getTexte1().split("#:#");
        //                  //DoctorName.setText(mListe.get(position).getTexte1());
        //                  String nameOfChatterProper[]=null;
        //                  if(nameAndText[0].contains("@"))
        //                  {
        //                      nameOfChatterProper=nameAndText[0].split("@");
        //                      nameOfChatter.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + nameOfChatterProper[0] + "</b>"));
        //                  }
        //                  else
        //                  {
        //                      nameOfChatter.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + nameAndText[0] + "</b>"));
        //                  }
        //
        //                  Msg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Msg);
        //                  Msg.setText(Html.fromHtml(nameAndText[1] ));
        //
        //                  TimeDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TimeDate);
        //                  if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("#:#"))
        //                  {
        //                      String str[]=mListe.get(position).getTexte2().split("#:#");
        //                      TimeDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(str[1])); 
        //                  }
        //                  else
        //                  {
        //                      TimeDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(getCurrentTime())); 
        //                  }
        //                  deliver = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deliver);
        //                  deliver.setImageResource(R.drawable.sent_group_chat);
        //              }
        //          }
        //          else if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("You"))
        //          {
        //
        //              convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rightchat,null);
        //              doctorStatus= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        //              doctorStatus.setImageDrawable(mListe.get(position).getImage());
        //
        //              myImage1= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage1);
        //
        //
        //              nameOfChatter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfChatter);
        //              String nameAndText[]=mListe.get(position).getTexte1().split("#:#");
        //              //DoctorName.setText(mListe.get(position).getTexte1());
        //              String nameOfChatterProper[]=null;
        //              if(nameAndText[0].contains("@"))
        //              {
        //                  nameOfChatterProper=nameAndText[0].split("@");
        //                  nameOfChatter.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + nameOfChatterProper[0] + "</b>"));
        //              }
        //              else
        //              {
        //                  nameOfChatter.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + nameAndText[0] + "</b>"));
        //              }
        //
        //              DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        //              List<Contact> contacts = db.getProfilePicData(nameAndText[0].toLowerCase()+"@imyourdoc.com");
        //              for(Contact cn : contacts)
        //              {
        //                  doctorStatus.setImageBitmap(convertByteArrayToBitmap(cn.get_profilePic()));
        //              }
        //              db.close();
        //
        //              Msg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Msg);
        //              Msg.setText(Html.fromHtml(nameAndText[1] ));
        //
        //              TimeDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TimeDate);
        //              if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("#:#"))
        //              {
        //                  String str[]=mListe.get(position).getTexte2().split("#:#");
        //                  TimeDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(str[1])); 
        //              }
        //              else
        //              {
        //                  TimeDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(getCurrentTime())); 
        //              }
        //
        //
        //              deliver = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deliver);
        //              deliver.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.received);
        //
        //          }

    }
    else if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("Me"))
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftchat,null);

        doctorStatus= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        doctorStatus.setImageBitmap(mListe.get(position).getImageBtimap());

        myImage1= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage1);


        nameOfChatter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfChatter);
        if(mListe.get(position).getTexte1().contains("#:#"))
        {
            String nameAndText[]=mListe.get(position).getTexte1().split("#:#");
            String nameOfChatterProper[]=null;
            if(nameAndText[0].contains("@"))
            {
                nameOfChatterProper=nameAndText[0].split("@");
                nameOfChatter.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + nameOfChatterProper[0] + "</b>"));
            }
            else
            {
                nameOfChatter.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + nameAndText[0] + "</b>"));
            }

            Msg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Msg);
            Msg.setText(Html.fromHtml(nameAndText[1] ));

            TimeDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TimeDate);
            if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("#:#"))
            {
                String str[]=mListe.get(position).getTexte2().split("#:#");
                TimeDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(str[1])); 
            }
            else
            {
                TimeDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(getCurrentTime())); 
            }
            deliver = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deliver);
            //deliver.setText(Html.fromHtml(nameAndText[2] ));
            deliver.setImageDrawable(mListe.get(position).getImageStatus());
        }
    }
    else if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("You"))
    {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rightchat,null);
        doctorStatus= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage);

        myImage1= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage1);


        nameOfChatter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfChatter);
        String nameAndText[]=mListe.get(position).getTexte1().split("#:#");
        String nameOfChatterProper[]=null;
        if(nameAndText[0].contains("@"))
        {
            nameOfChatterProper=nameAndText[0].split("@");
            nameOfChatter.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + nameOfChatterProper[0] + "</b>"));
        }
        else
        {
            nameOfChatter.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + nameAndText[0] + "</b>"));
        }

        //          DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        //          List<Contact> contacts = db.getProfilePicData(nameAndText[0].toLowerCase()+"@imyourdoc.com");
        //          for(Contact cn : contacts)
        //          {
        //              doctorStatus.setImageBitmap(convertByteArrayToBitmap(cn.get_profilePic()));
        //          }

        //  db.close();

        Msg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Msg);
        Msg.setText(Html.fromHtml(nameAndText[1] ));

        TimeDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TimeDate);
        if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("#:#"))
        {
            String str[]=mListe.get(position).getTexte2().split("#:#");
            TimeDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(str[1])); 
        }
        else
        {
            TimeDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(getCurrentTime())); 
        }


        deliver = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deliver);
        //deliver.setText(Html.fromHtml(nameAndText[2] ));
        deliver.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.received);

    }
    else if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("FileGet"))
    {
        //          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_get,null);
        //
        //
        //
        //          final ImageView att_img= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.att_img);
        //          att_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //          String unerNameTemp = "",urlTemp="",thumbTemp="",time="";
        //
        //
        //          if(mListe.get(position).getTexte1().contains("#:#"))
        //          {
        //              String[] data=mListe.get(position).getTexte1().split("#:#");
        //              unerNameTemp=data[0];
        //              urlTemp=data[1];
        //              thumbTemp=data[2];
        //          }
        //
        //          //final String url = urlTemp;
        //          final String thumb = thumbTemp;
        //          final String userName = unerNameTemp;
        //          if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("#:#"))
        //          {
        //              String[] data=mListe.get(position).getTexte2().split("#:#");
        //              time=data[1];
        //          }
        //
        //          final TextView UserName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfChatter);
        //          UserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + unerNameTemp + "</b>"));
        //
        //
        //          final TextView file_Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Msg);
        //          file_Name.setText(mListe.get(position).getDownloadingTxtAndFileSize());
        //
        //          final TextView timeDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TimeDate);
        //          timeDate.setText(time);
        //
        //
        //          final ImageView myImage= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        //
        //          DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        //          List<Contact> contacts = db.getProfilePicData(unerNameTemp.toLowerCase()+"@imyourdoc.com");
        //          for(Contact cn : contacts)
        //          {
        //              myImage.setImageBitmap(convertByteArrayToBitmap(cn.get_profilePic()));
        //          }
        //          db.close();
        //
        //
        //          att_img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        //          {
        //              @Override
        //              public void onClick(View v)
        //              {
        //                  Intent intent = new Intent("com.doctor.download.Start");
        //                  intent.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position));
        //                  intent.putExtra("userNameMe", commanInstance.getUserName());
        //                  intent.putExtra("userNameYou", userName.toLowerCase());
        //                  context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        //              }
        //          });
        //
        //
        //          ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        //          progressBar1.setProgress(mListe.get(position).getDownloadProgress());
        //          progressBar1.setMax(mListe.get(position).getMaxValue());
        //          progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //          final Button accept = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.accept);
        //          final Button denai = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.denai);
        //          //Button view = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view);
        //
        //          final ImageView Deliver= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deliver);
        //          final ImageView myImage1FileGet= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage1);
        //
        //          accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        //          {
        //              @Override
        //              public void onClick(View v)
        //              {
        //                  att_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //                  try {
        //                      byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(thumb);
        //                      Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
        //                      att_img.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
        //                  } catch (Exception e) {
        //                      // TODO: handle exception
        //                      e.printStackTrace();
        //                  }
        //                  file_Name.setText("Tab Image for show in full screen.");
        //                  accept.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //                  denai.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //
        //              }
        //          });
        //          denai.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        //          {
        //              @Override
        //              public void onClick(View v)
        //              {
        //                  Intent intent = new Intent("com.doctor.download.Decline");
        //                  intent.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position));
        //                  context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        //              }
        //          });
        //          String FileGetStatus=mListe.get(position).getFileGetStatus();
        //          if(FileGetStatus.equals("Complete"))
        //          {
        //              att_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //              att_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //              try {
        //                  byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(thumb);
        //                  Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
        //                  att_img.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
        //              } catch (Exception e) {
        //                  // TODO: handle exception
        //                  e.printStackTrace();
        //              }
        //              accept.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //              denai.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //          }


    }
    else if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("FileSend"))
    {
        //          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_send,null);
        //
        //
        //          final ImageView att_img= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.att_img);
        //          String unerNameTemp = "",urlTemp="",thumbTemp="",time="";
        //
        //          final String imagePathForIntent;
        //
        //          if(mListe.get(position).getTexte1().contains("#:#"))
        //          {
        //              String[] data=mListe.get(position).getTexte1().split("#:#");
        //              unerNameTemp=data[0];
        //              urlTemp=data[1];
        //              thumbTemp=data[2];
        //          }
        //          imagePathForIntent=urlTemp;
        //
        //          //final String url = urlTemp;
        //          final String thumb = thumbTemp;
        //          final String userName = unerNameTemp;
        //
        //
        //          if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("#:#"))
        //          {
        //              String[] data=mListe.get(position).getTexte2().split("#:#");
        //              time=data[1];
        //          }
        //
        //          final TextView UserName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfChatter);
        //          UserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + unerNameTemp + "</b>"));
        //
        //
        //          final TextView file_Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Msg);
        //          
        //          if(mListe.get(position).getFileSendStatus().equals("Sending_Complete"))
        //          {
        //              file_Name.setText("File Sent");
        //          }
        //          else if(mListe.get(position).getFileSendStatus().equals("Complete"))
        //          {
        //              file_Name.setText("File Sent");
        //          }
        //          else if(mListe.get(position).getFileSendStatus().equals("Sending_Complete_delivered"))
        //          {
        //              file_Name.setText("File Delivered");
        //          }
        //          else if( mListe.get(position).getFileSendStatus().equals("Sending_Complete_Seen"))
        //          {
        //              file_Name.setText("File Seen");
        //          }
        //          
        //          
        //          final TextView timeDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TimeDate);
        //          timeDate.setText(time);
        //
        //
        //          final ImageView myImage= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        //          final ImageView Deliver= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deliver);
        //          Deliver.setImageDrawable(mListe.get(position).getImageStatus());
        //          final ImageView myImage1FileGet= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage1);
        //
        //
        //
        //          myImage.setImageBitmap(mListe.get(position).getImageBtimap());
        //
        //          try {
        //              //byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode("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");
        //              byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(thumb);
        //              Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
        //              att_img.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
        //          } catch (Exception e) {
        //              // TODO: handle exception
        //              e.printStackTrace();
        //          }
        //          att_img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        //          {
        //              @Override
        //              public void onClick(View v)
        //              {
        //                  Intent intent = new Intent("com.doctor.download.Start");
        //                  intent.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position));
        //                  intent.putExtra("userNameMe", commanInstance.getUserName());
        //                  intent.putExtra("userNameYou",commanInstance.getListKyeName());
        //
        //                  context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        //              }
        //          });
        //
        //          Button retry=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.retry);
        //          Button cancel=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        //
        //          if(mListe.get(position).getFileSendStatus().equals("Sending_Complete") || mListe.get(position).getFileSendStatus().equals("Complete")
        //                  || mListe.get(position).getFileSendStatus().equals("Sending_Complete_delivered") || mListe.get(position).getFileSendStatus().equals("Sending_Complete_Seen"))
        //          {
        //              retry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //              cancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //          }
        //          else if(mListe.get(position).getFileSendStatus().equals("Processing"))
        //          {
        //              retry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //              cancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //          }
        //          else if(mListe.get(position).getFileSendStatus().equals("Error") || mListe.get(position).getFileSendStatus().equals("Cancel"))
        //          {
        //              retry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //              cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //          }
        //          retry.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        //          {
        //              @Override
        //              public void onClick(View v)
        //              {
        //                  Intent intent = new Intent("com.doctor.upload.Start");
        //                  intent.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position));
        //                  intent.putExtra("ImagePath", imagePathForIntent);
        //                  context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        //              }
        //          });
        //          cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        //          {
        //              @Override
        //              public void onClick(View v)
        //              {
        //                  Intent intent = new Intent("com.doctor.upload.cancel");
        //                  intent.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position));
        //                  context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        //              }
        //          });
    }



    return convertView;
}//public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public String getUserName(String name)
{  
    String nameUser[] = null;
    if(name.contains("@"))
    {
        nameUser=name.split("@");
        return nameUser[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return name;
    }


}//public String getUserName(String name) 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public String changeNameToCapital(String name)
{
    if (name!=null && name.length() > 0) {
        return name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
    }
    else
        return name;

}//public String changeNameToCapital(String name) 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public String getCurrentTime()
{
    String currentTime = null;

    Date now=new Date();

    final String time = now.getHours()+":"+now.getMinutes();

    try {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
        final Date dateObj = sdf.parse(time);
        currentTime=new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm").format(dateObj);
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM) 
    {
        currentTime=currentTime+" AM";
    } 
    else 
    { // == Calendar.PM
        currentTime=currentTime+" PM";
    }

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

    currentTime=currentTime+" | "+formattedDate;
    return currentTime;

}//public String getCurrentTime() 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static Bitmap convertByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap)
{
    Bitmap bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap, 0,
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap.length);
    return bitMapImage;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where did you try to set the received message in your chat layout?

Comment: @HamidShatu i have not taken any layout for that.,i have taken single layout of chatscreen in which items are coming in listview

Comment: So, then how did you add the received message to your `ListView`? post that code.

Comment: @HamidShatu i have defiend my layout in my adapter class

Comment: I'm asking, how you added this newly received message to your chat screen?

Comment: wait i post that..,hamid sir is there any link to post code on server.like paste something?

Comment: you should post here.

Comment: @R.T. and did you can `notifyDataSetChanged();` on your adapter after receiving message?

Comment: if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("Me")){
convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftchat,null);
doctorStatus=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
doctorStatus.setImageBitmap(mListe.get(position).getImageBtimap());
myImage1=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage1);

Comment: @vitalyster i have not use dthat

Comment: wait i post my adapter class.where i did this..,i edit my code

Comment: @HamidShatu sir here is my updated code.

Comment: @vitalyster sir here is my updated code.

Comment: @R.T. I'm still not see where you add received message to existing adapter and notify listview about data was changed.

Comment: @vitalyster i have not use dnotified..,.and chat will recieved from right chat layout in adapeter

Comment: @vitalyster what  should i do??????/please help me

Comment: "layout" will not show any new messages until you explicitly add them to adapter and notify layout about changes. You have only code **how** to convert message to elements on screen, but you **do not** add any messages.

Comment: @vitalyster ok sir..,so for that what shold i do??please help me..:(

Comment: @vitalyster sir  pleas ehelp me...ar eyou there?

Comment: @R.T. how many times I should repeat? You must **add received message to adapter** and call **notifyDataSetChanged();**

Comment: @Navya- Hey Navya, can you pls  guide me from where you have taken reference for chat application . I am trying same but hard luck. Please give some reference of CHAT APPLICATION...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing wrong comparison..,just change this line in your adapter  class

use this

```
else if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("You"))
```

insted of this

```
else if(mListe.get(position).getTexte2().contains("you"))
```

you was using small,letter.,but in your rsponse your value is "You".

it will work....:)